# Add wallet feature to bitcoind (full node) after installation with --disable-wallet

Tags: bitcoind, wallet

I installed bitcoind with this configuration:

```
`./configure --without-gui --disable-wallet`
```

However, after it finished downloading the blockchain for a week, now I realize I actually do need the wallet feature. Is there a way to add it back (without another week of verifying the blockchain)?

Answer (score 1):

The data directory is independent of the installation. Just recompile with the wallet enabled, install the binary over your existing one, and it'll use the same data directory and all of the data inside of it.